# What is the magnitude of bias in censored regression when OLS is applied?

Tags: survival, least-squares, censoring

If my dataset comprises few censored variables (<1%) and I fit the OLS regression using a heteroscedastic resistant estimator (the residuals are not terribly heteroscedastic to begin with)- are the results valid?

Comment: your question body does not mention anything about survival analysis, so I've changed the title. I still left the tag though, since it might generate different answers. Please consider adding more details if the survival analysis is really important in your question.

Comment: @mpiktas, The data are indeed survival data in that the dependent var is the time from diagnosis until death. Out of 1500 patients I have 15 that are still alive and hence right censored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you observe $(y_i,x_i)$, which come frome censored regression model:

\begin{align}
y^*_i&=x_i\beta+u_i \\
y_i&= \max(y_i^*,0)
\end{align}
with $u_i|x_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$,

Then this model is equivalent to:

\begin{align}
y_i=x_i\beta+\sigma\lambda(x_i\beta/\sigma)+e_i,
\end{align}
where $E(e_i|x_i,y_i>0)=0$ and $\lambda$ is [inverse Mills ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills_ratio).

If you apply OLS ignoring truncation then you omit the term with Mills ratio, so it does not matter that you account for heteroscedasticity, your coefficients will still be biased. If as you say you have only few censored observations, then the bias might be small. But it is better to come to this conclusion by comparing both models.

I've lifted most of the material from [Wooldridge's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=cdBPOJUP4VsC&lpg=PP1&dq=wooldridge%20econometrics&hl=fr&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=wooldridge%20econometrics&f=false), page 524, so you can read more about it there. You should also check whether you observe truncation or censoring, since these are usually confused and different results apply.